# Segmentation fault when using libsqora.so.19.1 by multiple threads on Linux (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, multithreading, oracle, segmentation-fault, odbc

I am developing an application that is using the ODBC API directly by using the Oracel DB driver.
Everything worked fine as long I was running single threaded. But when I am using multiple threads then almost every SQL... function crashes the process.
Whatever I found seems to be that I am doing everything correctly, e.g. I establish the environment first and after that all threads just use the environment to create their own connection.
Calling SQLAlloc to get a connection handle still works, but calling SQLDriverConnectW results to a segmentation fault.

Then I made a very simple test program and I get the same result (I dropped handling the return code to make it short):

```
SQLHANDLE environmentHandle = SQL_NULL_HENV;

void testConnect() {
    SQLHANDLE connectionHandle = SQL_NULL_HDBC;

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, environmentHandle, &connectionHandle);
    SQLSetConnectAttrW(connectionHandle, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, SQL_NTS);
    // ...
    SQLDriverConnectW(connectionHandle, NULL, szConnectionString, cbConnectionString, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    // ...
}

void runMain() {
    SQLRETURN rc;

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &environmentHandle);

    // switch to ODBC 3.0
    SQLSetEnvAttr(environmentHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

    // This works:
    // testConnect();

    // This works NOT!
    std::thread threadObj(testConnect);
    threadObj.join();

    // ...
}

int main() {
    try {
        runMain();
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "error\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this program it crashes when calling SQLSetConnectAttrW.
Then I figured out, that it will crash already when I establish the environment if runMain is not called within the main thread.
If I change the main function to this, then I get a segfault already by calling SQLSetEnvAttr.

```
int main() {
    try {
        std::thread threadObj(runMain);
        threadObj.join();
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "error\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot imagin if there is a bug in the oracle db driver library. But I also cannot find a bug in my code.
Has anyone faced this issue before? Can someone help?

Thank you!

Regards
Sven

Comment: Turn on thread safety in the driver? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/odbc-driver.html#GUID-F08F34BC-F987-4F07-ADD9-EFA4705BD423

Comment: Hey Christopher,
As far as I know it is done by adding ";APA=T" to the connection string and it is the default value. But I don't reach this point because it crashes before.
Maybe to most interesing part is that it crashs already by establishing the environment (crashes at SQLSetEnvAttr) if I shift doing this task into a separate thread.

Maybe there is another way to configure the driver to be thread safety? I set already ORACLE_HOME to /tmp and put a config file at /tmp/network/admin/sqlnet.ora to test some settings. But I think this file is not used if you use the driver low level.